# Eclipse - Showing how eclipse runs project with java.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

When I run a Java project within the `Eclipse IDE`, I assume in the background it is simply calling `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` with certain parameters, such as the `classpath` it's using and the actual class it's running.

#### Is there a way I can make `Eclipse` show this invocation, with all it's parameters? Ideally I'd like to be able to `copy&paste` it into a command window to duplicate the running of the project outside of the `Eclipse IDE`.

Comment: Are you using Linux or windows? In Linux you can use a variant of ps to see what is generated (I don't know of an Eclipse based solution)

Comment: Isn't the classpath already shown in the Run Configuration menu?

Answer (score 17):

(Original Answer: February 2011)

Launch your program in debug mode in Eclipse.
You can then see the exact command in the properties of the Debug views (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg65195.html) or [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t96777.html))

> First run or debug one of the configurations.
>   In the Debug view in the Debug perspective, right-click the running process and select "Properties". The command line used to launch the configuration is displayed.

[Bug 10820](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10820) was about "[java launching] Launch config: show cmd line before launch"... but it is closed as WONTFIX.

---

Update (March 2012)

[bbuser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111786/bbuser) reports in the comment having

> had to remove `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:60019` from the command line shown in properties in the Debug view.
>   Otherwise I got connection errors.
>   Also changing `javaw.exe` to `java.exe` might be advisable

Comment: I had to remove `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:60019` from the command line shown in properties in the Debug view. Otherwise I got connection errors. Also changing `javaw.exe` to `java.exe` might be advisable.

Comment: @bbuser: interesting, thank you for this feedback. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.